# How to refresh submitHandler in jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'v got a problem with jQuery Validation plugin.
When I defined custom submitHandler, it's stored after first validation run.
I'm using submitHandler to send the Object via AJAX request, but when the object is changed after event trigger, it wont change in submit handler function.
Is there any way to refresh submit handler after each event trigger?

My code

```
$('.request-telephone-form-submit').click(function(){  
    var thisForm = $(this).closest('form');

    var postVars = new Object();
    postVars.name = $('.request-name').val();
    postVars.phone = $('.request-phone').val();

    thisForm.closest('form').validate({
        rules:
        {
            Name: {
                required: true,

            },
            Telephone: {
                required: true,

            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '...',
                data : postVars,
                success : function(response) {                      

                }
            });

        }

    })

});
```

Comment: can u make your code into a jsfiddle demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple errors here.

Move your `$.validate` call out of the `click` handler, and just do it directly in a `$(document).ready` block:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formID').validate({
        //options here
    });
});
```

If your `$('.request-telephone-form-submit')` is a submit button in the form, it will automatically validate when the button is clicked.  If the form validates according to your `rules`, then it will call the submitHandler function.  At that time you can collect your post variables like so:

```
   submitHandler: function(form){
       var postVars = new Object();
       postVars.name = $('.request-name').val();
       postVars.phone = $('.request-phone').val();            
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '...',
            data : postVars,
            success : function(response) {                      

            }
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle event on your form tag and use `$('form.formClass').on('submit', function(){})` that is better jQuery way